# Script to execute a task when certain TCP traffic appears (Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm)

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian, raspberry-pi, tcp

I am using a Raspberry Pi as a Wifi bridge in my kitchen at home to bring network connectivity to a device that only has ethernet.
I used a Will Haley guide and it works great. That part is solved however I also want this device to be able to seamlessly wake up my NAS but the feature isn't available on the client end device.

`etherwake` [MACADDRESS OF NAS] works great and perfectly wakes up my NAS from the Raspberry Pi bridge using terminal, so I just want to automatically do it based on a trigger.

When the Media App loads up on the client end device the following occurs as it tries to connect to the NAS (which is off) I used `pktstat` to display what follows:

`603.8 0% tcp 192.168.84.100:52787 <-> 192.168.84.2:21`

192.168.84.2 is the NAS and .100 is the client device... and I use a basic LAN ftp server to share media round the house hence the port 21.

How do I create a persistent script/service that listens for that TCP traffic and when it catches it then launches a secondary script (I already have the WOL).
The script also needs to only run when ping responses to the NAS fail to avoid it trying to wake it constantly?

If I can have this running on the Pi it means than whenever someone opens the Media player in the kitchen it will then also wake up my NAS if it is off. That will be so useful for my family.

Nowadays the price of electric means its super nice to have my NAS off when its not required so it can sleep. Most of my other equipment has WOL function so I am trying to manually create it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All credit to Ljm Dullaart's help below is a working solution to the question:

```
#!/bin/bash
interfacename=eth0
IPofNAS=192.168.84.2
MACADDRESSofNAS=AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:EE
timeout=300

while : ; do
    tcpdump -nt -i $interfacename -c1 dst $IPofNAS and port ftp
    if ! ping -c1 $IPofNAS ; then
        etherwake -i wlan0 $MACADDRESSofNAS
    fi
    sleep $timeout
done
```

Originally the script would constantly wake up my NAS, because tcpdump was finding ARP requests for the NAS' IP, these were occurring whilst the client device was off and they were just occurring on the Pi. Took me a while to spot that. In addition tcpdump writes port 21 as 'ftp' so when I added port 21 to filter down the script it stopped working all together. After seeing in tcpdump raw output that ftp was in plain text I added it like that.

Cant thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

A possible way would be to monitor all trafic going through the Pi and going to the NAS. If there is trafic, wake-up the NAS. In a script that would be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
interfacename=eth0
IPofNAS=192.168.84.2
MACADDRESSofNAS=00:11:22:etc
timeout=600

while : ; do
    tcpdump -nt -i $interfacename" -c1 dst $IPofNAS
    if ! ping -c1 $IPofNAS ; then
        etherwake $MACADDRESSofNAS
    fi
    sleep $timout
done
```

Explanation:
`tcpdump -nt -i $interfacename -c1 dst $IPofNAS` dumps a single packet (`-c1`) that goes to the NAS (`dst $IPofNAS`). No DNS resolution, no timestamping (`-nt`).

When such a packet is received, a test with `ping` is done to see if the NAS reacts; if not: `etherwake` is started.

Then we'll wait for a period of `$timeout` before we start again to prevent ping-flooding the NAS. The `$timeout` should be around the time-out before the NAS goes into sleep. You might want to experiment with that a little.

You can ask `systemd` to start this script. Create `/etc/systemd/system/wolNAS.service` with the content

```
[Unit]
Description=WOL of the NAS

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/the_script_above.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(disclaimer: not tested)

Comment: Wow thats so simple and clean, I'll test that out as soon as I can, thanks for the explanations also, I heard this was a good spot to come to actually learn.

The NAS will always be on for a period of 20 minutes minimum, there is a script running on the NAS that checks if there is anyone connected to it, once no one is connected it it goes to sleep after 20 minutes. This could be 20 minutes after a film finishes etc or sometimes when someone accidentally opens an app that wakes the NAS. How does this effect the appropriate time out?

Comment: It depends a bit and you'll have to experiment a bit for the right value of `timeout`. For a NAS time-out of 20 minutes, I would set the script `timeout` to 15 minutes (1800 secs) for a start.

Comment: Hey thanks again dude.

So i've done some testing and the ping part is working great, IE if there is no ping the script will wake up the NAS but it doesnt seem to be relying on this tcpdump statement, the script seems to not care about this step and always be just checking if there is a ping, if there is no response from the NAS IP then it just wakes it rather than checking if there is indeed a packet being sent to the NAS from the client prior to then moving onto the next step and checking for a ping. So in this scenario the script will just constantly wake up the NAS every timeout cycle.

Comment: figured out why the script kept waking the NAS over and over.....it was due to TCPDUMP capturing ARP requests on the Pi and then satisfying that line. I answered the question based on the good work already put here.